# click() is working with Thread.sleep() is working in 2 seconds but implicitlyWait is not working at all in Selenium 3

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am using Firefox 50.0.2 and Selenium  java 3.0.1
Here is the code:

```
WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
d.manage().window().maximize();
// d.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
d.get("http://www.quikr.com");
WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(d, 5);
w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.sign-up")));
Thread.sleep(2000);
d.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.sign-up")).click();
```

When I comment out  the Thread.sleep(2000) and uncomment the implicitlyWait() the **sign-up button is not getting clicked**. I have also tried with pageLoadTimeout() also which worked only once.I wanted to know why implicitlyWait() is now working even after 20 seconds whereas Thread.sleep(2000) works within 2 seconds.

Comment: if you use the wait condition the button is not clicked but you receive a timeout exception? you could also do everything in a oneliner: (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.sign-up"))).click();

Answer (score 0):

Is your event handler, attached using a `document.ready` in which case the element become "clickable" (the event is handled) after it becomes visible. So a more accurate condition would be `elementToBeClickable`